# Download a file remote server that uses different port and private key

Tags: download, port, remote-server, scp, pem

I need to download a file from a remote server to my local. The SSH is running on a non-standard port and the remote server required a private key to connect to it from local.

I know how to achieve it separately:

For non standard port it is:

```
scp -P 2222 username@example.com:/backup/file.zip /local/dir
```

For server using private key it is:

```
scp -i private_key.pem username@example.com:/backup/file.zip /local/dir
```

But how can I download a file that require connecting to a non-default port as well as uses pem file (private key file)?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scp -i private_key.pem -P 2222 username@ip_address:/backup/file.zip .
```

This worked for me.